# Web Deploy Error with Azure

Tags: azure, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy my web app to Azure using [this method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud/archive/2011/04/19/enabling-web-deploy-for-windows-azure-web-roles-with-visual-studio.aspx), but periodically, i get this error.  Any ideas?  I rebooted the instance, still happens.

```
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://xxx.cloudapp.net:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=myapp.Web_IN_0_myapp.Web ...
Updating setAcl (myapp.Web_IN_0_myapp.Web).
Updating setAcl (myapp.Web_IN_0_myapp.Web).
Updating filePath (myapp.Web_IN_0_myapp.Web\bin\myapp.Web.dll).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): Warning : An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create File' on 'myapp.Web.dll'.  
Retrying operation 'Update' on object filePath (myapp.Web_IN_0_myapp.Web\bin\myapp.Web.dll). Attempt 1 of 2.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): Warning : An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create File' on 'myapp.Web.dll'.  
Retrying operation 'Update' on object filePath (myapp.Web_IN_0_myapp.Web\bin\myapp.Web.dll). Attempt 2 of 2.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): Error : Web deployment task failed.((9/28/2011 8:00:56 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

(9/28/2011 8:00:56 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create File' on 'myapp.Web.dll'.
The error code was 0x80070020.
The process cannot access 'E:\approot\bin\myapp.Web.dll' because it is being used by another process.
Publish failed to deploy.
========== Build: 3 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: WaIISHost.exe seems to have it locked.   This dll seems to be the one defined as the Web Role EntryPoint.  If I kill WaIISHost.exe manually, i seem to have about a minute to copy the dll over before WaIISHost automatically restarts.  

I've tried to move the entry point into another DLL, but it didn't fall for that trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create a bootstrap csproj for your web role, that does nothing.  This will be the DLL that gets locked by WaIISHost.

Then create the real web projects as separate sites using the  option in the csdef file.  Once you've done this, you can deploy any of your sites using web deploy and they will work, as long as they have no reference to your bootstrap dll (since they won't copy that file)