# Error "The stream data of file is not yet available." publishing Web Role Azure Project

Tags: deployment, azure, azure-web-roles

I have set up a Windows Azure project using the Windows Azure SDK plugin to Visual Studio. There is one Web Role in this project that points to a couple websites in the same solution. I have configured the publish settings for the azure project and was able to push azure project as a whole without problems.

I don't want to push the whole role deployment each time (and be forced to wait for the instances to be rebuilt.) Sometimes I just want to push a few web file changes directly to the existing web instance.

Azure appears to understand this and automatically creates a publishsettings.pubxml file in the web projects. However, when I right-click on one of the web projects and select "Publish" I get the following error:

> Error 112 Web deployment task failed. ((1/28/2013 10:49:05 AM) An
>   error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (1/28/2013 10:49:05 AM) An error occurred when the request was
>   processed on the remote computer. **The stream data of
>   'C:\dev\[solution]\[project]\obj\Dev\Package\PackageTmp\bin\[project].dll'
>   is not yet available.**

I have jiggled all the handles I can find, and cannot get past this error.

Comment: Adding a [dummy web role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592043/web-deploy-error-with-azure) allows us to publish just the web project, but creates another web role that we would have to pay for.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I do have the same problem

Comment: My first comment links to a really yucky hack to get it working. I think it's a bug in the Azure Project deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish a "partial" solution to a cloud service.  You can only publish the Cloud Project and all roles in that project.  This is why Azure has the concept of Staging and Production deployments.  You publish your changes to staging, test them, swap the VIP when happy and then delete the old deployment.  Azure load balancers handle moving clients during the VIP swap to prevent client downtime.

If you are running more than one instance in Production, then you can update the deployment directly and Azure will update the instances one at a time and again handle moving clients with the load balancer.

Comment: I should caveat that we've been able to do this before. Not sure why this error is suddenly occurring. If we do a fresh azure project publish, we can usually "Publish" directly from the web project once or twice before getting this error.

Comment: Not sure if it was at the time of this answer, but Web Deploy is now supported on Web Roles.