# Azure Web Role - Multiple websites don't compile when debugger is run in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-web-roles

I have an Azure Cloud Service Project that has a web role with multiple websites associated with it.

When I click the "run" button, it fails to load the debug symbols for all the websites in the web role. In order to debug the other websites, I have to explicitly build the web project in question before I can run the debugger.

How can I configure the Azure Cloud Service Project to compile all the associated webs within a single web role?

Answer (score 0):

As of this posting, Visual Studio 2012 support for multiple websites within a single web role is fairly poor ([Exibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569839/error-the-stream-data-of-file-is-not-yet-available-publishing-web-role-azure), [Exibit B](http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/)).

When you click the "Run" button in a solution, it doesn't mean that all projects will be compiled. Only those directly related with the project that is being run at the moment will be compiled (and debug symbols updated).

Consider the following work-around:

1. Identify the main web role web project in the solution (it should the one that
   matches the name of the web role in the Azure Cloud Service Project).
2. Right click on the web project
3. Go to "Add Reference"
4. Go to "Solution"->"Projects"
5. Check the checkbox next to each of the web role's associated websites.
6. Click OK

By adding a reference to the other web projects, it causes the compiler to compile the other webs when the Azure Cloud Service Project is run with the debugger.

This will allow you once again hit the "run" button with great abandon.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted some details on using multiple web sites within a web role on my blog at http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/.

As for the debugger, are you using host headers for the different sites?  If so, try switching to use different ports instead.  I've had better luck going that route for debugging purposes.  Then switch back to host headers when ready to deploy.

Comment: LOL . . ooops.  Help if I clicked on all the links.  My bad.